# When creating a text file, should it appear in the project navigator straight away?

Tags: python-3.x

Yesterday, all files created appeared in the project navigator as soon as it was created. But today, with no changes made to the code, for some reason the files only appear in the navigator after I execute other parts of the code or when I terminate the code. I'm including all of the code because it's when the user chooses options 3, 4 and 5 that the files suddenly appear in the navigator. As I said, yesterday, the files appeared as soon as they were created but for some reason today they don't, even though I have made no changes to the code.

```
import sys

def main():

    main_menu_choice = input("""Please choose from the following
    1. Register a child.
    2. Register a staff member.
    3. Children.
    4. Staff.
    5. Exit.""")

    if main_menu_choice == "1":
        child_first_name = input("Enter the child's first name")
           # check that no empty string or digit is entered
        if child_first_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in 
child_first_name):
            print("Invalid entry.")
            main()
            return()
        else:
            child_last_name = input("Enter the child's last name")

        if child_last_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in 
child_last_name):
            print("Invalid entry.")
            main()
            return()
        else:
            child_name = (child_first_name + " " + child_last_name).title()

        file = open("Children.txt", 'a')
        file.write(child_name + "\n")
        file.close()
        main()
        return()

    elif main_menu_choice == "2":
        staff_first_name = input("Enter the staff member's first name")

        while staff_first_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in 
 staff_first_name):
            print("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease start again.")
            main()
            return()

        else:
            staff_last_name = input("Enter the staff member's last name")

        while staff_last_name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in 
staff_last_name):
            print("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease start again.")
            main()
            return()

        staff_name = (staff_first_name + " " + staff_last_name).title()

        file = open("Staff.txt", 'a')
        file.write(staff_name + "\n")
        file.close()
        main()
        return()

    elif main_menu_choice == "3":
        file = open("Children.txt", 'r')
        lineList = file.readlines()
        lineList.sort()
        print("List of children's names in alphabetical order:")
        for line in lineList:
            print(line, end="")
        file.close()

    elif main_menu_choice == "4":
        file = open("Staff.txt", 'r')
        lineList = file.readlines()
        lineList.sort()
        print("List of staff member's names in alphabetical order:")
        for line in lineList:
            print(line, end="")
        file.close()

    elif main_menu_choice == "5":
        print("Exit.")
        sys.exit(0)

    else: #If an invalid choice was made from main_menu_choice
        print("Invalid Command, try again.")
        main()
        return()
main()
```

Comment: Files appearing in an IDE is very dependent on the IDE. To see what's actually going on you could pull up a terminal to the directory in question and list the files after each action.

Comment: The IDE hasn't changed either since yesterday.

Comment: Is this your actual indentation?

Comment: sorry, wrong indentation.... post edited to show correct indentation now.

Comment: First of all, `return` isn't a function, in fact your are returning a empty tuple. Just write `return`. And your code isn't good. Don't use recursivity, use while loops to verify the input.

Comment: Yes, I want to return an empty tuple, to end the recursiveness. My script works fine as it is, my question wasn't about the use of the return() function.